# Spring data Jpa implementar métodos genéricos

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jpa

Tenho 3 services com estes métodos em comum `create()`,`deleteById()`,`findAll()`,`getById()`  e `update()`.

```
@Service
public class AutorService {create(),deleteById(),findAll(),getById(),update(), etc...}

@Service
public class GrupoService {create(),deleteById(),findAll(),getById(),update(), etc...}

@Service
public class GeneroService {create(),deleteById(),findAll(),getById(),update(), etc...}
```

Pretendo transforma-los em interface e criar a implementação com a business logic nelas.

Seria uma boa pratica criar uma interface com esses métodos em comum para estender em seguida implementa-los? Porque toda vez tenho que ficar criando esses métodos.

Exemplo:

**GenericService** com os métodos em comum

```
public interface GenericService<T, I extends Serializable> {

    List<T> findAll();

    T getById(Long id);

    T create(T entity);

    T update(T entity);

    void deleteById(Long id);
}
```

**AutorService** extend GenericService e tem seu método findByNome()

```
public interface AutorService extends GenericService<AutorEntity,Long>{

    public AutorEntity findByNome(String nome);
}
```

**AutorServiceImpl** implementa GenericService com os método do AutorService

```
@Service
public class AutorServiceImpl implements AutorService {/*.....*/}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente, todos os seus services irão ter os mesmos métodos de crud, como, `save`, `delete`, `find`, `findAll`, etc. Eu recomendo que você crie uma interface genérica passando o tipo da entidade como parâmetro. Esta interface deve conter a assinatura desses métodos, e em seu service(Interface) você herde desta interface genérica.

Para sua implementação, você pode criar uma classe abstrata genérica que implemente sua interface genérica e sobrescreva os métodos, e em seu service(Implementação) você irá herdar desta classe.

Uma outra boa prática é na sua classe abstrata, você criar métodos como, preSave e postSave, assim, quem deseja aplicar alguma regra de negócio, pode implementar o método e escrever sua regra sem estragar o código.

Comment: Ola @Felix bem vindo ao ptSO, Obrigado pelo seu tempo para contribuir com uma resposta. [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Com certeza a utilização adequada de interfaces é uma boa prática, elas irão garantir que mantenha-se um padrão ao longo do projeto devido forçarem a implementação dos métodos definidos nela. Outra vantagem que gosto bastante em aplicadas-las é quanto a documentação do código, por exemplo:

Digamos que vc tenha uma empresa onde existem 3 categorias de função, a comissão salarial para cada função exige uma fórmula de cálculo diferente, neste caso utilizo uma interface, e a documentação dela repercutirá nos métodos gerados partir da implementação da mesma.

```
public interface Funcionario {

    /**
     * Retorna o valor da comissão recebida por determinado empregado.
     * @param taxa
     */
    BigDecimal calcularComissao(BigDecimal taxa);

}
```

Todas classes quem implementem esta interface receberão nos métodos gerados a documentação correspondente. Vc garante que a documentação também estará padronizada.